# IIRF not working with ASP.NET postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, postback, reverse-proxy, iirf

I have the following scenario.

- **Web server A**: public on the Internet, [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) (Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter, current version) installed
- **Web server B**: not public, on the intranet, visible to A, my ASP.NET web application is installed on, name is **pgdbtest3**

I configure IIRF so that any request targetting directory **/MMS/** on server A is redirected to the corresponding one in B: **http://pgdbtest3/MMS/**. The ini file looks like:

```
StatusUrl /iirfStatus  RemoteOk
RedirectRule ^/MMS$         /MMS/          [I]
ProxyPass   ^/MMS/(.*)$    http://pgdbtest3/MMS/$1  [I]
```

It is working fine except that any **post back** causes an error (404 is returned). I have tried many solutions including the removal of the action attribute from the form but with no luck.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you need ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse? This has worked for me in the past but I am having troubles today.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using URL rewriting the <form> control does not render the proper URL but the re-written one. The solution is to write a form control adapter. Check the solution in *[Handling ASP.NET postbacks with URL Rewriting](http://ruionwriting.net/blog/2013/10/01/handling-asp-dot-net-postbacks-with-url-rewriting/)*.